# Cuando ejecuto mi programa me marca un error de string no a sido inicializado

Tags: c++, poo

Hola estoy aprendiendo programación orientada a objetos. La cosa es que uno de los ejercicios que estoy haciendo consistía en crear una clase vehículo y allí introducirle el precio entre otras cosas. Ejecute mi programa y me marca el siguiente error

```
[Error] 'string' has not been declared
```

**Mi clase vehículo**

```
class vehiculo{
private:
    char marca, modelo;
    float precio;
public:
    vehiculo(){
    }
    mod(string marc, string mod, float pri);
    masbar(vehiculo a[], int len);
};
```

**Codigo donde declare las funciones**

```
    #include "masbar.h"

void vehiculo::mod(string marc, string mod, float pri){
    marca = marc;
    modelo = mod;
    precio = pri;
}

int masbar::masbar(vehiculo a[], int len){
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= len; i++){
        if(a[i].precio > a[max]).precio{
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Agradeceria cualquier ayuda.

Comment: te falta importar, include string.h

Comment: @x-rw en [tag:c++] (aún) no se importa, se incluye.

Answer (score 2):

Ojo, cuidado. Estás mezclando conceptos: Declarar, definir e inicializar son conceptos diferentes. Tu error:

> Ejecute mi programa y me marca el siguiente error
>
> ```
> [Error] 'string' has not been declared
> ```

Hace referencia a la **declaración**, pero en el título de tu pregunta indicas que te falla la inicialización. Y es un error (muy) diferente al que te encuentras.

Vamos a ilustrar cada uno de los conceptos:

- **Declaración**: Al declarar un objeto, le estás diciendo a tu compilador que ese objeto existe, no es necesario dar detalles del objeto para declararlo, basta con darle nombre, ya que si das detalles de cómo es el objeto entonces se trata de una...
- **Definición**: Cuando se define un objeto, le estás dando al compilador detalles del mismo como sus métodos y sus variables miembro. Si no existe declaración previa, una definición cuenta como declaración y definición.
- **Inicialización**: Un objeto definido se puede [instanciar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instancia_(inform%C3%A1tica)); las instancias pueden recibir un valor inicial y cuando ésto sucede decimos que se ha inicializado.

---

Por lo tanto, tu problema es imposible que sea de inicialización, pues para poder inicializar algo primero debes declararlo, y tu compilador te dice que no has declarado ese algo, te traduzco el mensaje de error para más claridad:

> Ejecute mi programa y me marca el siguiente error
>
> ```
> [Error] 'string' no ha sido declarado
> ```

Así que tampoco es cierto que tu programa haya fallado al ejecutar como has indicado, no se puede ejecutar algo que no ha sido compilado y el error que mencionas previene la compilación.

Lo más probable, tal y como ha mencionado [Germán Martínez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/234082/2742) es que se te haya pasado incluir la cabecera `<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que te falta incluir el archivo **string** y definir que estas usando el espacio de nombre **std**

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

Además de esto veo que tenés otros errores, por ejemplo en cuando definís los métodos **mod()** y **masbar()** en la clase vehiculo, te falta especificar el valor de retorno.

```
class vehiculo{
private:
    char marca, modelo;
    float precio;
public:
    vehiculo(){
    }
    mod(string marc, string mod, float pri);  // Aquí tenés que definir el tipo de retorno
    masbar(vehiculo a[], int len); // Aquí tenés que definir el tipo de retorno
};
```

Otro error que veo es que en la implementación del método **vehiculo::mod()**, estás asignando un string a un char.

```
void vehiculo::mod(string marc, string mod, float pri){
    marca = marc; // ERROR: Estás asignando un "string" a un "char"
    modelo = mod; // ERROR: Estás asignando un "string" a un "char"
    precio = pri;
}
```

Otro error, es cuando intentas implementar el método **masbar()**, es que estás asignandoselo a una supuesta clase **masbar** cuando debería ser **vehiculo**, lo que escribistes es:

```
int masbar::masbar(vehiculo a[], int len){
 // Codigo
}
```

Y debería ser:

```
int vehiculo::masbar(vehiculo a[], int len){
    // Código
}
```

Otro error que veo, es que en el método **masbar()**, escribis mal el **if**, escribistes

```
if(a[i].precio > a[max]).precio{
    max = i;
}
```

Deberías escribir así

```
if(a[i].precio > a[max].precio){
    max = i;
}
```

O sea, pusistes el paréntesis antes ".precio" y tiene que estar después.

Comment: `using namespace` no es para nada obligatorio. Leyendo tu respuesta parece que es imprescindible usarlo

Comment: Claro que no es obligatorio, pero tal cual presento el código, sí, porque sino hubiera escrito std::string.

Comment: En esto último estoy de acuerdo, pero es mejor decirlo así que dar a entender que el uso de `using namespace` es obligatorio